# Пользовательские атрибуты для замерения скорости работы кода

Tags: c#

Я хочу реализовать пользовательский атрибут, который с помощью stopwatch будет замерять время работы кода. Я подключил атрибут к методу main. Но ничего не отображается на консоли. Не пойму, как правильно написать такой атрибут?

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All )]

class TestAttribute : Attribute
{
    private Stopwatch stopwatch;

    public void RunTime()
    {
        stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
    }

    public void ShowTime()
    {
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}

class Program
{
    [TestAttribute]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

В вашем случае методы `RunTime` и `ShowTime` это просто методы атрибута: сборка о них ничего не знает и не будет вызывать до и после вызова метода, как вы, наверное, ожидали.

Нужный вам функционал реализован в классе [OnMethodBoundaryAspect](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/Day-4-OnMethodBoundaryAspect.aspx) из библиотеки [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/). Использовать можно следующим образом.

```
[Serializable]
[MulticastAttributeUsage(MulticastTargets.Method, Inheritance = MulticastInheritance.Multicast)]
class TestAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    private Stopwatch stopwatch;

    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
    }

    public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

Если вам, как и мне, интересно решение задачи без использования PostSharp, предлогаю следить за [этим вопросом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851150/how-does-onmethodboundaryaspect-works).